# Unable to set label text from class method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, methods, awt

So basically I am beginning to learn Java's awt and swing libraries and while programming a basic calculator the only problem I encountered was that at the time that you press one of the buttons to do the operation, the result label is unreachable from the operation method, notice it is instantiated first and it does work when I do it all from the same method, say the constructor (instantiate the label, get the input, and generate the output).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    double a,b;
public GUI(){
    setTitle("Calculator");
    setVisible(true); //Initializes window frame
    add(panel); //Initializes window panel
    input1();
    input2();
    result();
    addition();
    subtraction();
    multiplication();
    division();





    setSize(400,500);
}
void input1(){ //Sets Input 1 label and input box
    JLabel lInput1=new JLabel("Input 1"); 
    lInput1.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(lInput1);
    JTextField tInput1=new JTextField(4);
    panel.add(tInput1);
    a=Double.parseDouble(tInput1.getText()); //Saves the input on a variable for later usage
}
void input2(){ //Sets Input 2 label and input box
    JLabel lInput2=new JLabel("Input 2"); 
    lInput2.setForeground(Color.green);
    panel.add(lInput2);
    JTextField tInput2=new JTextField(4);
    panel.add(tInput2);
    b=Double.parseDouble(tInput2.getText()); //Saves the input on a variable for later usage
}
void addition(){ //Sets addition button
    JButton addition=new JButton("+");
    panel.add(addition);
        addition.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            result.setText(String.valueOf(a+b));
            }
        });
}
void subtraction(){ //Sets subtraction button
    JButton subtraction=new JButton("-");
    panel.add(subtraction);
        subtraction.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            result.setText(String.valueOf(a-b));
            }
        });
}

void multiplication(){ //Sets multiplication button
    JButton multiplication=new JButton("*");
    panel.add(multiplication);
    multiplication.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        result.setText(String.valueOf(a*b));
        }
    });
}
void division(){ //Sets division button

    JButton division=new JButton("/");
    panel.add(division);
        division.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            result.setText(String.valueOf(a*b));
            }
        });
}
void result(){
    JLabel result=new JLabel();
    panel.add(result);
}
}
```

The error appears in the lines that have the following method:

```
result.setText();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `result` is declared as a local variable to the `result` method, if you wish to be able to access in at a class level you will need to make it an instance field

Comment: Maybe [Scope of variables in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) might help better

Comment: So how can I do that? I attempted to declare both the method and the instance as public, but it's not possible.

Comment: Do one or the other, not both (otherwise you end up shadowing your variables)

Comment: I meant I tried both separately, but it says that only final is allowed for the result instance. Do you mean that the only way to do it is declaring the result field inside the constructor instead of in a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic Java 101, it might worth while spending some time understanding how scope works in Java

The basic answer is to make the variable an instance field of the class...

```
//...
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    //...
    JLabel result=new JLabel();
    //...
    void result(){
        panel.add(result);
    }    
}
```

This way it will be accessible to the whole object

> but it says that only final is allowed for the result instance

I'd find it hard to believe that it would be "required" to be final, it wouldn't hurt in this case, but you're just adding complexity to the problem which you might not be ready for yet.  If you want to silence the IDE/compiler warnings, then by all means, mark it as `final`

```
final JLabel result=new JLabel();
```

Comment: It's not that it has to be final, just that in case of adding a modifier the only one available is that one.

Comment: I think it does require it to be final since it is being used from an anonymous class

Comment: @AdamsonJeremiah I'd only need to be `final` if it were a local variable, instance fields are uneffected